# How to bind scope to dynamically added html from directive?

Tags: angularjs-directive

Below is the simple script when I repeat scope variable names and using directive **usescope**, the functionality I need is when we click on name it should add **Hello name **, However I couldn't bind scope. Could someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="name in names track by $index"> 
            <td data-usescope=""> {{name}} </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script   
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   
      integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('app', []);

      app.controller('test', function($scope) {
        $scope.names = ["Test1","Test2"];
      });

      app.directive('usescope',
        function ($compile) {
          return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    element.append($compile('<span> Hello {{name}} </span>')(scope));
                });
            }
        };
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest following solution. A working example can be found at - [@sumit Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yDuaiSPK7MfTOebsuTeG?p=preview) Here's a code sample:

```
<body ng-controller="test">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">
        <td data-usescope="name"> {{name}} </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

app.directive('usescope',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      scope: {
        'name': '=usescope'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var compiledeHTML = $compile("<span id='span1'> Hello " + scope.name + "</span>")(scope);
          element.append(compiledeHTML);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```